# Set WKInterfaceGroup height less than 2 points

Tags: swift, watchkit

I cannot change height of WKInterfaceGroup less than 2 points. Interface builder just replace a number (`1` in my case) with `2`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just call `setHeight(1)` on a target object.